# how to display data by day month year laravel?

Tags: laravel

I want to display data based on day, month, year I have tried but not displayed at all.

```
public function today()
{
    $videos = Video::whereBetween('created_at', [now(), now()->addDays(7)])
    ->orderBy('created_at')
    ->get()
    ->groupBy(function ($val) {
        return Carbon::parse($val->created_at)->format('d');
    });

    return view('video.today', compact('videos'));
}
```

in view

```
@foreach ($videos as $video)
{{ $video->title }}
@endforeach
```

[image: Screenshot of the view]

Comment: write this statement  dd($videos); just above return statement is there any data?

Comment: As @NeerajAmoli said, be sure that `$videos` aren't empty at first. But also, you will need two `foreach` since you group them by the day.

Comment: Are you sure your collection contains video's? You are fetching all videos 7 days in the future.

Comment: @NeerajAmoli the result empty Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#349 ▼
  #items: []
} even though there is video data

Comment: @Jerodev yes I have only one video

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you do `->groupBy()` on collection, I suggest doing it on `SQL` (MySQL Solution):

```php
public function today()
{
    $videos = Video::whereBetween('created_at', [now(), now()->addDays(7)])
    ->orderBy('created_at')
    ->groupBy(\DB::raw('DAY(created_at)')) //YEAR(created_at) //MONTH(created_at)
    ->get();

    return view('video.today', compact('videos'));
}
```

This will group the videos by `day` on SQL level.

Note: as @Jerodev said in comment your are fecthing future videos change you `where` to:

```php
whereBetween('created_at', [now()->subDays(7), now()])
```

OR

```php
whereDate('created_at', '>=', now()->subDays(7)->toDateString())
->whereDate('created_at', '<=', now()->toDateString())
```

This will fetch videos for last 7 days.

Comment: data videos still do not appear

Comment: I want to display all video data in a choice of Sunday or month like this https://prnt.sc/qa8h95

Comment: @ptcarudi try with `whereDate` (updated answer) ( and based on screenshot you don't need `groupBy` unless you want to count them.

Comment: this appears but only one video is displayed, the other video does not appear even though the date is the same.

Comment: data that appears only one video even though I have 3 with the same date https://prnt.sc/qa9bhd

Answer (score 0):

> Try this:

```
Carbon::parse($request->created_at)->format('d-m-Y');
```

Comment: data that appears only one video even though I have 3 with the same date prnt.sc/qa9bhd